# Maven & Nexus handling SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: maven, nexus, nightly-build

My project has 10 or so reusable components, each in their own repository, versioned independently, but do rely on each other for builds.

Right now, each component has their own nexus SNAPSHOT repository and a custom nexus group for nightly builds so I can be sure the nightly build of a component only includes 3rd party and the other components it needs.  Specifically, the group will not have the component's own snapshot repository.  This way I can detect when a jar has been removed but I've forgot to clean up a pom dependency on it.  The build will break, rather than silently succeeding because it found an old SNAPSHOT jar.

But this is a huge pain from a management perspective and from what I've seen of public nexus repositories (and the sonatype book) is to have a single repository for a team or organization, rather than per component.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Is there a way to install a nexus black list in the component pom so it will not try to download certain artifact/group id combinations?

Comment: Do all these components belong to the same project?

Comment: They are all used for a bigger project, but they were designed to be reusable libraries.  We have multiple "projects" (top level projects if you will) that use 1..n of the components.

Answer (score 0):

A black list in pom's is not possible. I assume your setup of your project is wrong.

I would suggest to create a multi module project for your **project** which has all the modules (reusable components).

```
   big-project (pom.xml)
      +--- module1 (pom.xml) 
      +--- module2 (pom.xml) 
      +--- module3 (pom.xml) 
      +--- module4 (pom.xml) 
      ..
```

which will give you the advantage having only a single version of all components together and a simple solution to build them together without maintaining the dependencies and in particular in different versions and having a consistence state of your project cause you can see which component (module) works with which versions of other components.

In your setup it's really hard to know which version of which component works with an other component in a particular version.

Apart from the above it makes it simpler to create integration tests as part of the build more simpler like this:

```
   big-project (pom.xml)
      ..
      +--- it-mod (pom.xml)
      ..
```

Furthermore you can use separate modules (components) from other projects as well.

Using different SNAPSHOT repositories in nexus does not make sense, cause every component should have a groupId/artifactId/version coordinate so you can use a single SNAPSHOT repository otherwise you have a maintenance hell for the repositories which you having experience with.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible.  In our case, moduleX is a self contained application...  It exists on it's own outside of big-project.  We don't want to put it in the same maven project so it can be developed independently of the other modules.